# Can't get rid of VALUE error when using excel-formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've written a formula in excel which is able to find any specific text from a column, no matter how many times it has appeared. The issue I'm facing is that the cells which doesn't have the result show value error. How can I get rid of this value error? In the following example I tried to find "TORRES" from column A. Using my formula I get that in column B but the value error comes along like shown in the image.

Here is the formula I was trying with:

```
=IF(A1=SEARCH("TORRES",A1),A1,A1)
```

Here is the image containing results along with value error:

[image]

Btw, When nothing found I want those cells to be blank.

Comment: can "TORRES" occur as "   TORRES  " or "TORRES mi amor" something like that?  And what you want to have in column B, when it was found?  and when it was not found?

Comment: When it is not found I want those cells to be blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the VALUE error, because there's not always "TORRES" in the column.

You can hide that with `IF(ISERR())`:

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("TORRES",A1)),"",A1)
```

Edit: Updated per your comment under the OP.

This will check if the `SEARCH()` finds `TORRES`. If it doesn't, returns `""`, if it does, it returns the value.

Comment: why not `IFERROR`?

Comment: @DirkReichel - I wasn't sure what OP wanted, so did the `IF(ISERR())`, but after his comment, I'll update to include that option.  ..Edit: Wait, how would I do `IFERROR` to return something if true?

Comment: Impressive. It does the job. Thanks a zillion BruceWayne.

Comment: @BruceWayne IFERROR returns the results of the function when there is no error, and when there is an error returns whatever you place after the comma,`IFERROR(FUNCTION,ERROR RESULTS OPTION)`

Comment: @ForwardEd - Oh, for sure. But if I did `=IFERROR(SEARCH("TORRES",A1),"")`, it just returns `TRUE`, not `TORRES`.

Comment: @BruceWayne I see what you are saying.  Yes, your search part would need to be modified if using IFERROR.  Apparently I am still waking up and its almost time to go home!  Side bar for future readers, FIND and SEARCH do the same job, but one is case sensitive.